# Performance and Memory optimization hints of an knockout based application

Tags: javascript, json, knockout.js, leaflet

We have made a web client where you can pushpin markers on a map and multiple users can comment on each of these markers. For the map we use [leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) and (what matters more) [Knockout](http://knockoutjs.com/) for the ViewModel of these Pushpins and the comments on it.

So the data model isn't too complicated: Each Pushpin has a Lat/Lon, Title, some Metadata (who and when created it) and an array of comments (each with Username, Timestamp, Text).

There are a couple of computeds in the view model (firstComment, lastComment, etc..), that Knockout has to keep up to date, so I think these are slowing it down a lot.

Everytime the app starts, we download the whole set of Pushpins (over 600 right now) as JSON and initialize the Knockout view model with it. The JSON already has about 1,2 MByte which lasts already 6 seconds to download. The initialization of the Knockout View Model then needs over 20 seconds. I created a splashscreen with some animated GIF, so the user doesn't think that the App doesn't work, but as Pushpins are getting more this behaviour gets worse.

Javascript also needs a lot of memory to build up the model. I think memory is needed for the Knockout model, and also for the markers for the leaflet layer, which is its own model associated with my knockout objects.

In Firefox Memory rises up to about 700MB when I open my web app. In IE9 its over 1 GB (!). Also when the knockout model is built up (mainly creating Knockout observables and pushing them to an observable array) browsers are not reacting anymore. In IE the website (and my splashscreen) isn't rendered at all until Knockout has done its job. In Firefox the website gets rendered first, then it freezes until the model is built up, then it comes back again. In Chrome its the same as it is in IE.

Another issue is, that memory does not get freed except when I close the browser. With every site reload another GB is allocated so I can easily fill up every Byte of my 8GB Laptop by refreshing my site eight times ... :(

I already thought about extending our REST Server API with some kind of pagination, and to lazy load much of the data as late as possible. But first I would like to know, what Knockout offers to get my model with a lot of data (in fact it isn't much at the moment, but it could get much) up and running without freezing the browser for a couple of seconds.

How do you handle a large amount of knockout objects in the browsers memory and how to you lazy bind it?

Comment: Look up Web Feature Services, hosted on GeoServer. These are free, open source solutions: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/services/wfs/reference.html Basically, your issue is you are downloading EVERYTHING at once. You need to download what the user needs, but only when they need it. Using WFS, you can download the geometries for the user's view. When the user clicks a feature, you can lazy load JUST the comments for that single feature. This is all handled via dynamic web requests, using WFS and WFS-T. It may seem a bit daunting at first - but trust me, this is the solution you want.

Comment: To add: I've used Knockout/Leaflet with thousands of objects before, each with dozens of ko.observables, and never really had much slow-down, with efficient coding. The slow-down you are experiencing is likely due to your specific implementation. To answer questions of optimization, someone would need to see your specific implementation.

Comment: You are right for sure. I also know Geoserver very well. I only wanted to keep it very simple because...I mean...its only about some simple pushpins/markes, not a very spatial sophisticated application. I just wondered if there are patterns, for example to bind leaflet markers to an observable array without fiddling around with subscriptions. Did you ever implement a leaflet layer as a computed for example?

Comment: Or patterns to lazy load also would be interesting... just loading a list of pushpins first...when it gets selected, init the content of the single item with knockout and present its comments in a leaflet bubble... I couldn't find good examples on this. I doesn't have to belong on leaflet, just an good example of an Knockout application which loads content on demand would help me a lot.

Comment: A simple lazy load pattern would be to disassociate the geometry of the pushpins from the comments for each pushpin. When your application loads, ONLY load the geometries and create those markers. Loading the geometry for 600 pushpins would take no time at all. Then, when the user clicks the Popup, you can go back to your initial data source and get the comments for that specific pushpin. From here just populate the Popup. If you want to use KO for creating the Popup based on your comments, then you can simply create a ViewModel dynamically and apply it to the Popup content div container.

Comment: I had ko crash an app once with out of memory - I was blindly using ko.mapping to turn EVERYTHING into an obesrvable, when I really only needed a few properties of each object. Customizing my mapping changed memory usage from 400mb to about 10 in my case...maybe that method will help you.

Comment: @scaryman ok, thats interesting...because I also need to get my all pushpins and parts of their comments, because depending on the last comment I paint different markers on my map. But some properties don't have to be loaded at startup time, only when a user wants to read all the comments. How did you solve this, to only load some of the properties, and at a later time the rest? Did you have to put any logic into the server or did you solve all this only by changing your mapping?

Comment: Mine was basically the difference between `var pageVM = ko.mapping.fromJS(SerializedModelWIthAllTheData)` and `var pageVM = SerializedModelWIthAllTheData; pageVM.Products.forEach(function(p) { p.Name = ko.observable(p.Name);})` 

so the first example every single data item, even ids, are observables and taking up memory. In the second, the only observable in the giant products list is the product name.

I have no idea if that's applicable to you because you didn't post any code though. But I bet your solution is a combination of lazy loading and selective observable creation.

Comment: 600 objects in a JSON array takes 1.2 MB of data and 6 seconds to download? what do you have an itel atom server and a dial up connection? I have sent over 30 thousand json items for a report using the same time and package size... it seems there's a lot of room for improvement here so please share more details on your implementation and i'll be glad to give you help